# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL 2008 server through hibernate.it's not getting connected, following is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>    
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">1234</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TEST</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property> 
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`

And here is the code I use to try and establish an connection and do a query :

```
package com.simpleprogrammer;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
public class HibernateUtilities {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static {

try {
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure().addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}catch(HibernateException he){
System.out.println("Problem Caught ! " + he );
}
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

`

The Main method :
    package com.simpleprogrammer;

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Hello World!") ;
Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Could you specify `not getting connected`? Any error messages or something?

Comment: in HibernateUtilities  class line 
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
gives an error of
**com.simpleprogrammer.HibernateUtilities.<clinit>(HibernateUtilities.java:20)**  .. **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException**

Comment: It is also preferable to edit your question instead of adding additional information using the comments^^

Comment: So u also dn't know how to fix ^_^ it

Comment: i fixed it. it was missing some jar files and now u know .. lol

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, feel free to write an explicit answer to your own question describing the fix. This may help other users in the future

Comment: the following jar file was missing **jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0** . which i add to my project library and it start working

Comment: No...please add that as an answer, not as a comment. The same way you add additional information by editing your question and not as a comment. You can read all of this in the help section as well. If you follow these guidelines it will be much easier for other users with similar problems. If you do that it is also preferable to remove all these comments afterwards as they do not have any use ten

Answer (score 0):

jar file was missing **jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0**, Simply add it in project and it start working